# Multi instance of Jhipster generator on the same PC

Tags: java, npm, jhipster

I want to use several Jhipster generator on my PC.

When I've installed the generator for the first time, with the command

```
npm install -g generator-jhipster
```

The result has been I've in the folder c:\Users\MyUser\Appdata\Roaming the global version about Jhipster generator, so when I try to check the version with command

```
jhipster --version
```

I've got the messagge:

```
INFO! Using Jhipster version installed globally (and the version number i.e. 6.8.0)
```

Now I want to install, only for a project a new Jhipster geenrator (i.e. 6.5.1) but I don't know how I can install locally about this project

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to your project directory and run `npm install generator-jhipster@6.5.1`.

When there is a local `node_modules` directory, jhipster prefers it over globally installed version.

You can check version with `jhipster --version` it should print this:

```
INFO! Using JHipster version installed locally in current project's node_modules
6.5.1
```

Comment: Actually, it didn't work for me. still using global version.

Comment: Have you tried using `npx jhipster --version` ? if it shows same version, have you checked which version is indeed installed in local node_modules folder?